# Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, redux

- to write unit test case, I have exported my class SportsTopPortion.
- but I am facing the below error
- I did a google for the error and found below links
  https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5927
- I went through the links but not sure how to fix it
- providing my code below and entire code be found in fiddle
  https://jsfiddle.net/1LLgjtsa/1/

```js
 /*
        Expose Non-connected component for unit testing
     */
    export { SportsTopPortion };

    export default connect(state => ({
        sportsAuthentication: state.template.sportsAuthentication,
        sportsPlayers: state.template.sportsPlayers,
        sportsUpperBar: state.template.sportsUpperBar
    }))(SportsTopPortion);


-even I changed class syntax but still not working

let SportsTopPortion = React.createClass({
    getInitialState () {
        return {
            disableMenuAnimation: false,
            isAuthenticationFlowActive: false,
            mobileMenuOpen: false      
        };
    },

/*class SportsTopPortion extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            disableMenuAnimation: false,
            isAuthenticationFlowActive: false,
            mobileMenuOpen: false
        };
    }*

**error**
```

Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).
C:\sports-whole-page\node_modules\fbjs\lib\invariant.js:45
    throw error;
    ^

Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
    at invariant (C:\sports-whole-page\node_modules\fbjs\lib\invariant.js:39:15)
    at instantiateReactComponent (C:\sports-whole-page\node_modules\react\lib\instantiateReactComponent.js:64:134)
    at instantiateChild (C:\sports-whole-page\node_modules\react\lib\ReactChildReconciler.js:29:28)
    at traverseAllChildrenImpl (C:\sports-whole-page\node_modules\react\lib\traverseAllChildren.js:98:5)
    at traverseAllChildrenImpl (C:\sports-whole-page\node_modules\react\lib\traverseAllChildren.js:114:23)
    at traverseAllChildren (C:\sports-whole-page\node_modules\react\lib\traverseAllChildren.js:186:10)
    at Object.ReactChildReconciler.instantiateChildren (C:\sports-whole-page\node_modules\react\lib\ReactChildReconciler.js:52:5)
    at ReactDOMComponent.ReactMultiChild.Mixin._reconcilerInstantiateChildren (C:\sports-whole-page\node_modules\react\lib\ReactMultiChild.js:197:41)
    at ReactDOMComponent.ReactMultiChild.Mixin.mountChildren (C:\sports-whole-page\node_modules\react\lib\ReactMultiChild.js:232:27)
    at ReactDOMComponent.Mixin._createContentMarkup (C:\sports-whole-page\node_modules\react\lib\ReactDOMComponent.js:591:32)
    at ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.mountComponent (C:\sports-whole-page\node_modules\react\lib\ReactDOMComponent.js:479:29)
    at Object.ReactReconciler.mountComponent (C:\sports-whole-page\node_modules\react\lib\ReactReconciler.js:37:35)
    at [object Object].ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent (C:\sports-whole-page\node_modules\react\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:225:34)
    at [object Object].wrapper [as mountComponent] (C:\sports-whole-page\node_modules\react\lib\ReactPerf.js:66:21)
    at Object.ReactReconciler.mountComponent (C:\sports-whole-page\node_modules\react\lib\ReactReconciler.js:37:35)
    at [object Object].ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent (C:\sports-whole-page\node_modules\react\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:225:34)

Comment: Please format your post better, it's quite hard to read as is. Also that error usually happens when you try to import a default exported class using curlies: instead of `import SportsClass from '....'` you're doing `import { SportsClass } from '....';`

Comment: @ZekeDroid can you update in my fiddle...its confusing :( ...i tried formatting..its not working in sstack

Comment: no, it's equally as confusing also there's information missing like the tests. Instead, post the tests here. Also, maybe read up on how to properly format code in SO. It's not that hard once you learn the syntax.

Comment: @ZekeDroid hey I formatted the code...the  error is not in my test...its in my js file ``` export { SportsTopPortion }; ```  can you tell me how to fix it I tried all ways :(

Comment: right, just do `export SportsTopPortion`. Assuming that's a defined class that's all you need to export it

Comment: also add it to the bottom of the file, not the top

Comment: @zeke I added at the bottom and tested...still same error...you can see my fiddle for whole code

Comment: the fiddle still shows you exporting the class with curlies

Comment: @ZekeDroid But if I remove curlies it's throwing syntax error :( i have updated my fiddle too https://jsfiddle.net/1LLgjtsa/2/

Comment: @ZekeDroid  can you please help

Comment: I don't know what else could be wrong. If there was a working online copy of your code it might help figure out what's wrong. Have you tried narrowing down the issue? try removing all dependencies and exporting the class by itself. Then try removing most things from the class.

Comment: @ZekeDroid hey today morning that error went away but right now when I  run my existing test case its throwing ` TypeError: Cannot read property 'propTypes' of undefined `  -----> `this line shallowRenderer.render(<SportsTopPortion ` you can see my gist here https://gist.github.com/js08/47c56dff0e4b75a281ae

Comment: well clearly it has to do with your `propTypes` somewhere. Go back to your source code and remove them one by one until you see the one that is messing up. Then fix it.

Comment: @ZekeDroid but clearly I am passing valid proptypes in my test case but still errror...any idea `let sportsContentContainerLayout ='mobile';
    let sportsContentContainerProfile = {'exists': 'hasSidebar'};`

Comment: @ZekeDroid hey I even changed the proptypes inside the class like but still not working...will there be any other issue `let SportsTopPortion  = React.createClass({

    propTypes: {
        sportsWholeFramework: React.PropTypes.string,
        sportsPlayers: React.PropTypes.object
    },`

Comment: @ZekeDroid: - when the server is running and I include the export line its not throwing an error and able to see the application...even it shows webpack is valid
 export { SportsTopPortion  };
- but after including this line and start the server again I am facing the error
Error: Invariant Violation:

Comment: way too many variables. don't know what to tell you

Comment: @ZekeDroid what does this mean-----> way too many variables

Comment: too many things could be going wrong :/ it's best to ask specific questions on this site

Comment: @zeke I will post another question and let you know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107793/discussion-between-texi-rv-and-zekedroid).

Comment: The error is telling you the exact problem. One of your props is an object, and not a string. Go through all your props and find the offending prop.